# Describing the shape of orthogonal complements to points in arc

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

I define a circle $T$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with equations $y^2+z^2=3/4$ and $x=-1/2$.  This circle lies on the unit sphere $S$.  I define the set $B$ to be all points on $T$ with y-values between $\epsilon$ and $-\epsilon$ and positive z-values (that is, a small arc at the top of $T$).  For every two points in $B$, consider their corresponding vectors, and find the unit vector orthogonal to both.  (Assume we choose the orthogonal vector with positive x-value).  Let's call the set of all of these orthogonal vectors $C$.  (I will also use $C$ to describe the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ corresponding to these vectors).

My question is, what does $C$ look like (as a set of points)?  Is it also an arc of a circle?  Perhaps a circle parallel to the xy-plane?  For my research problem I'm trying to show that we can choose $\epsilon$ small enough that the points of $C$ will be very close together (this seems obvious to me but I'm having trouble showing it).  Instead of defining $T$ as is, is it better to define a larger circle closer to the Prime Meridian (so to speak) of $S$?  Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "corresponding vector"? Do you mean the radial vector from the origin to the point?

Comment: Yes.  So the point $(-1/2, 1/4, \sqrt{11}/4)$ would have corresponding vector  $<-1/2, 1/4, \sqrt{11}/4>$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a precisely quantitative answer.
Just attempting to track the specified geometry.
I used $\epsilon=0.1$ radians to delimit the subset $B \subset T$.

> My question is, what does $C$ look like (as a set of points)?

It "looks like" as indicated below:

---

[image: SphereArcQ]

---

Pardon that I did not

> (Assume we choose the orthogonal vector with positive x-value)

but instead showed both $\pm$.

$C$ appears to be bounded by a circular arc connected to a `V`
whose angle is determined by $\epsilon$,
in particular, the straight-line boundaries of $C$ are orthogonal
to the $\epsilon$ extremes of $B$,
as is the circular arc boundary,
more clearly seen from $(+\infty,0,0)$:

---

[image: Smiley]

---

In any case, have a nice day! :-)

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! So it seems that by choosing a smaller arc of the circle $T$, I can make that red orthogonal region as small as I need.

Comment: @BradElliott: Yes.